# jQuery + php file upload. Pass multiple parameters

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, upload

How to pass extra variables through $.ajax to post.php?

My first variable is

```
var form_data = new FormData($(this)[0])
```

I can pass it alone, but if I want to add another variable and make an array

```
data {
    "form_data": form_data,
    "name": "hello"
}
```

it does't work.

My current code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("form#data").submit(function(){

        var form_data = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'post.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: form_data,
            success: function (data) {

                $('#result').html(data); 

            },
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });

        return false;
    });
});

<div id="result"></div>

<form id="data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file" type="file" />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you make me a [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) to look at?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. The `formData` object has a method `append`. We're going to use that instead. We're going to append the file under the name file. In PHP access it with `$_FILES['file']`. Now for the array or object that you want to add to it. Use `JSON.stringify` on it to turn it into a string. We append the JSON string and add it to the name 'object'. To access the JSON in PHP `json_decode($_POST['object'])` will turn it into an object.

Fiddle

```
$(function(){
    $("form#data").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form_data = new FormData(),
            o = {};
        o.name = 'Adam';
        o.arr = ['test', 213];
        form_data.append('file', $('input[name="file"]', this)[0].files[0]);
        form_data.append('object', JSON.stringify(o));
        $.ajax({
            url: '/info/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: form_data,
            success: function (data) {

                $('#result').html(data);

            },
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would JSON.stringify it then json_decode when you get it back in PHP

var data = JSON.stringify({ /* object */ });

Then in your php
$data = json_decode(....);

Answer (score 0):

Try to define  a new bariable

```
var name = "hello";
```

and then insert it into `$.ajax` `data`

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'post.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: "form_data="+form_data+"&name="+name,
        success: function (data) {

            $('#result').html(data); 

        },
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
```

I never test this script, but there's no matter to check it out :D